# Python and SQLite3: Query must return 2 lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm using this query to verify whether 2 waypoints (x[0] and x[2]) are on the given route:

```
c.execute("SELECT WPNumber, ROUTE, WPID FROM wpnavrte WHERE ROUTE = ? AND (WPID = ? OR WPID = ?)", (x[1], x[0], x[2]))
```

If both waypoints are on the route, the result should be something like `[('001', 'A123', 'WAYPOINT X'), ('005', 'A123', 'WAYPOINT Y')]`

If the waypoint/route combination is false, it'll either return None, or one list.

What is the most pythonic way to check whether the result of the query is a double list (or not)?

Comment: Check the length is equal to 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest is to amend your SQL query slightly (applying a `LIMIT 3` to lighten the query, then check you've only got 2):

```
results = list(c.execute("SELECT WPNumber, ROUTE, WPID FROM wpnavrte WHERE ROUTE = ? AND (WPID = ? OR WPID = ?) LIMIT 3", (x[1], x[0], x[2])))
if len(results) != 2:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

```
c.execute("""SELECT t1.WPNumber, t1.ROUTE, t1.WPID, t2.WPID
    FROM wpnavrte t1
    JOIN wpnavrte t2
    ON t1.ROUTE = t2.ROUTE
    WHERE t1.ROUTE = ? AND t1.WPID = ? AND t2.WPID = ?
    """, (x[1], x[0], x[2]))
```

If the two waypoints are on the same route, then `c.fetchone()` will return a 4-tuple with values representing the WPNumber, Route, first and second WPID.

If the two waypoints are not on the same route, `c.fetchone()` will return `None`.

Comment: Interesting... depends on if the DB can optimise the join... I think just limiting the query result as it's a simple WHERE is possibly better...

Comment: @JonClements: Yep, you're method is much faster :). On potential problem with using `(WPID = ? OR WPID = ?)` would be if the WPIDs are not unique. In that case you might get two records back even if only one WPID is matched. That seems unlikely in this case given the *names* of the columns, but that's just an assumption.